# Different equations for linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model, notation

I don't have statistics background but I am studying LMM and trying to understand why different resources have different notation. Based on my reading I tried following as simple model with random intercept and slope:

```
 Y ~ 1 + A + (1+A|B)
```

According to [this (behind paywall)](https://methods.sagepub.com/book/multilevel-modeling/n2.xml), the equation should be

[image]

According to [this (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model), the equation should be

[image]

My question is regarding B(1j). 1) In the R syntax I showed, which is the correct equation? 2) What is the difference in interpretation of two equations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither are correct. Both formulations are for a model with two covariates, $X$ and $W$.

For your model:

```
Y ~ 1 + A + (1 + A|B)
```

this has the following features:

- a global intercept, let us call it $\beta_0$
- a random intercept, let's call it $u_{0j}$, where $j$ indexes the groups of `B`
- fixed effects for `A`, let's call it $\beta_1$
- random slopes for `A` within levels of `B`, let's call it $u_{1j}$
- residual error, let us call it $e_{ij}$ for the $i$th observation within the $j$th group of `B`

We could write this model as:

$$ Y_{ij} = \beta_0 + u_{0j} + ( \beta_1 + u_{1j}) A  + e_{ij} $$

Thus each subject $j$ has it's own intercept, which we could call $\beta_{0j} = \beta_0 + u_{0j}$, and it's own slope for $A$, which we could call $\beta_{1j} = \beta_1 + u_{1j}$, thus we could easily re-write this as:

$$ \begin{align}
\text{Level 1: } \qquad
 Y_{ij} &= \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1j}A  + e_{ij} \\
\text{Level 2: } \qquad
 \beta_{0j} &= \beta_0 + u_{0j} \\
 \beta_{1j} &= \beta_1 + u_{1j}
 \end{align}
$$
which is similar to the formulations in the question.